# How to use a variable as a key with i18next?

Tags: javascript, node.js, i18next

I am trying to use a variable as a key for a localisation using [i18next](https://www.i18next.com). Although, the right strings are returned but the interpolation does not work.

I tried to play with variables and raw strings to see where the issue comes from. I am sure it comes from the use of variables in `i18n.t()`.

```js
return newChannel.guild.channels.get(config.defaultChannel).send(i18n.t(message.content, message.options));
```

`message` value is returned by a function. This is a snippet:

```js
else if (newChannel.name !== oldChannel.name) {
    return message = {
        content: i18n.t('events:channel.update.name.text'),
        options: { oldChannel: `**#${oldChannel.name}**`, newChannel: newChannel, interpolation: { escapeValue: false }}
    };
}
```

That is the string in the json:

```
"update": {
    "name": {
        "text": "The text channel {{oldChannel}} is now called {{newChannel}}."
    }
}
```

It outputs: `The text channel  is now called .`

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `message.content` and `message.options`? I assume that one is `update.name.text` and the other is supposed to contain `oldChannel` and `newChannel`. Generally the interpolation happens by matching the key names, so I would guess without knowing the content that you have a mismatch.

Comment: Thanks for reading! I update my question :) .

Comment: No one can help me? :(

Answer (score 0):

This snippet looks incorrect:

```
else if (newChannel.name !== oldChannel.name) {
    return message = {
        content: i18n.t('events:channel.update.name.text'),
        options: { oldChannel: `**#${oldChannel.name}**`, newChannel: newChannel, interpolation: { escapeValue: false }}
    };
}
```

It should be something more like:

```
else if (newChannel.name !== oldChannel.name) {
    return message = {
        content: i18n.t('events:channel.update.name.text'),
        options: { oldChannel: oldChannel.name, newChannel: newChannel.name, interpolation: { escapeValue: false }}
    };
}
```

Note the changes to both variables. Can you explain what you are trying to do in the mappings that makes you feel that you need to do string interpolation with ES6 instead of just using the interpolation that the library itself supports?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Your modification changes what I want to display. `oldChannel.name` isn't the same as `**#${oldChannel.name}**`.

I think i didn't understand what you meant by your question. I set `escapeValue` to false because otherwise, it didn't display the way I wanted.

Comment: The `oldChannel.name` should be fine as `**#${oldChannel.name}**`; I was just asking about the extra interpolation. But the second variable, `newChannel` is an object, and it appears that you are intending to display the property `newChannel.name`, which would fail in you example.

Comment: The object returns can be displayed this way with what I use. It returns a text which is a link (that's why escapeValue is set to false. This worked at other places. Is it because I return the value message to use it somewhere else? And in this case, variables in `message.options` aren't transmitted?